# If I do not install openssh when creating an ubuntu server, can someone still SSH into the server?

Tags: ssh, openssh

Ubuntu server gives me the option to install openssh. If I reject this, is there anything more I must do in order to completely disable SSH from my server?

Comment: "openssh" is vague. The package you seemingly don't want is `openssh-server`. Removing (or not installing) that package will indeed prevent SSH logins, as no service will be listening for connection attempts. No other action is necessary.

Comment: How do you plan to access the server? Wouldn't it be better to configure "sshd" properly? There are decades of `sshd` experience available on the Internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Background:**

1. OpenSSH is the premier connectivity tool for remote login with the SSH protocol, It encrypts all traffic to eliminate eavesdropping.
2. The OpenSSH server component, sshd (ssh deamon), listens continuously for client connections from any of the client tools.

**To your specific question:**

3. As far as i know and read on official ubuntu site https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-openssh **sshd does not comes by default on ubuntu server.**
4. To be sure that you do not have sshd installed, you can run this command `which sshd`.
5. Furthemore you can check the default file of the `sshd` configuration `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` which should not be found.
6. You can also make sure that your server is not listening to `ssh` port by run the command `netstat -tulpn4`.

   - note that the default port for `sshd` service is 22.
   - to be able to execute `netstat` command you have to install `net-tools` which can be installed by `sudo apt install net-tools`
   - the output of executing `netstat -tulpn4`  will be by this format:

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1122            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3333            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           -
```

7. **To avoid ssh access to your server you can:**

   - not install sshd in the first place.
   - install and disable the sshd service by this command `systemctl disable sshd.service`

**In Addition:**

8. **There are few more services that`s enabling shell connection to a server:**

   - `dropbear` - lightweight SSH server.
   - `telnet` - user interface to the TELNET protocol, The telnet command is used for interactive communication with another
     host using the TELNET protocol.
   - **if you wanna make sure that your server is safe from any type of connection it is recommended to check that those services are disabled or uninstalled.**
   - **Note that a configuration solution can also be found to secure the server.**
   - **Finally, it is recommended to use the `netstat` tool and examine all the open ports on the server in order to detect security gaps and understand the server services.**